# WPF: Transparent Splashscreen flickers, why?

Tags: c#, wpf, png, transparency, splash-screen

I am using Visual Studio 2013, and can reproduce the following behaviour:

1. Create a new WPF Application
2. Add a transparent PNG to my project, and select "Splashscreen" from the Build Action menu
3. Make the Mainwindow big enough so that the SplashScreen overlaps the Mainwindow on startup

What happens when I build and start that application is: the splashscreen appears, stays for some fragements of a second, disappears when the Mainwindow is drawn, and then flickers again for a very short period of time.

As I mentioned, this seems to be related to transparent images overlapping the main window, but I find that behaviour very annoying. Is there any way to fix it, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did u check this link ? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d855eb24-7eb4-4034-b8d3-21782ac56a2d/flicker-in-a-splash-screen?forum=wpf

Comment: @ArulManivannan The MSDN forums never cease to amaze me. The OP for that post never got back to the answerer, it *may not have even worked* and the question was *still* marked as **answered**.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `topMost` to `true` fixed this for me.

```
SplashScreen splash = new SplashScreen("splash.png");
splash.Show(true, true);
                    ^------ Here
```

To get rid of the flicker, you have to do this in code.

Comment: Show method takes only one parameter

Comment: @kmalmur: [This overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.splashscreen.show?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_SplashScreen_Show_System_Boolean_System_Boolean_) takes two.